# Why is the drag detected event not fired every time?

Tags: java, javafx, drag-and-drop

I want to use javafx drag and drop handler to move a javafx Node (specifically a Group) around. This works fine the first time I move the Group (click on the Group... drag it on the screen... let go... the Group changes position).

But right after the successful first move, I cannot move the Node again, because the DRAG_DETECTED event is not fired. In order for the DRAG_DETECTED event to be fired again, I have to do something with the mouse (move it slightely or click somewhere) before I can drag and drop the Group again.

(My workaround is to move the mouse via java.awt.Robot slightely by 1px, then I can drag the node immediately every time. But this hack does not seem like the correct solution)

Can you tell me, why the DRAG_DETECTED event is not fired, when I try to start a drag gesture immediately after moving a Node?
Is there a proper way to solve this?

Thanks for your help.

Here is my relevant code:

```java
source.setOnDragDetected((event) -> {
  Dragboard db = view.startDragAndDrop(TransferMode.ANY);
  ClipboardContent content = new ClipboardContent();
  content.putImage(source.getImage());
  db.setContent(content);
  event.consume();
});

target.setOnDragOver((DragEvent event) -> {
  if (event.getGestureSource() instanceof SourceClass) {
    event.acceptTransferModes(TransferMode.MOVE);
  }
  event.consume();
});

target.setOnDragDropped((DragEvent event) -> {
  if (event.getGestureSource() instanceof SourceClass) {
    ((SourceClass)event.getGestureSource()).getObject().setLocation(
        event.getX(), event.getY()); // this changes an observable object 
                                     // which then calls its observer 
                                     // "target" which will call 
                                     // source.relocate(x, y);
    event.setDropCompleted(true);
    /* Now following the hack to move the mouse slightely, but only workaround. */
    Platform.runLater(() -> {
      try {
        Robot robot = new Robot();
        robot.mouseMove((int)event.getScreenX()+1, (int)event.getScreenY()+1);
        robot.mouseMove((int)event.getScreenX(), (int)event.getScreenY());
      } catch (AWTException e) { }
    });
  }
  event.consume();
});
```

Comment: You are blocking the UI thread by calling `Thread#sleep` inside `Platform#runLater`.

Comment: I am not entirely sure, but since you are moving the group (if  I understand correctly) upon dropping, maybe try forcing re-layout of the container (by calling `Parent#layout` on the parent containing the group)?

Comment: Hi @silliyfly. The blocking UI thread is one of the reasons I would like to solve it more elegantely :-). At least I took the `Thread#sleep` out and the hack still seems to work.
However running the `Parent#layout` function did not solve the problem, I'm afraid. Any other ideas, why I have to move the mouse before being able again to drag and drop?